# is there any package to extract a particular keyword in Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I have comments like "the product name with ch12345 and tp12345".

I want to extract from these comments keywords that start with `ch` or `tp` followed by a two or three digit number. How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Please don't forget to post your code so that we can help you.

Comment: The comments are entries in the SQL database? Which db do you use?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **Regular Expressions**. They are a sublanguage used to describe *patterns* of text you would like to match in a string. For your particular example, the regex (short for *reg*ular *ex*pression) would be something like this:

```regex
(ch|tp)\d{2,3}
```

which I'm sure looks quite complicated. What it actually means is the following:

```
a digit character - that is:
either 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9
       /\
(ch|tp)\d{2,3}
\_____/  \___/
 `ch`    Last thing (the \d)
   or     repeated from 2 to 3 times.
 `tp`
```

Python also provides the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html) module for working with regular expressions. Here is an example for your case:

```py
# Import `re` module (builtin)
import re

# Create the pattern we want to match
pattern = re.compile(r'(ch|tp)\d{2,3}')

# Given some string `inputString`
inputString = "… ch123 tp44 …"

# Extract the matches
matches = re.findall(pattern, inputString)
```

You should be able to adapt this for use in whatever database library you are using - in fact, it may even have it's own regex support.